# CSS class name autocomplete (IntelliSense) not working for "cshtml" files in VS Code (Suggested approaches did not work)

Tags: visual-studio-code, razor, autocomplete, intellisense

Although I have installed "HTML CSS Support" and "IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML" extensions and they work on other files, but they don't work with "cshtml" files.

I appreciate any solution.

**Update**

I understood that in this project of mine the "CSS class name" extension is not even activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now the only way worked for me was to add a CSS file into the project, even without linking it to any file.